# Plotshape and label syntax error; too many arguments

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

In below code, I am getting syntax error for plotshape and several for label.  Even for max / min I am getting too many arguments. I used label to get the value from intraburst formula as text.  Will need help to resolve these.

```
//@version=4 
study("Intraburst", overlay=true)

truemove = abs(open[2] - close) dayTrueHigh = max(high[1], high,
close[2]) dayTrueLow = min(low[1], low, close[2]) dayTrueRange =
dayTrueHigh - dayTrueLow intraburstLevel = truemove / dayTrueRange *
100

if intraburstLevel > 30
    plotshape(series=intraburstLevel, text="ON", style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.normal) else
    plotshape(series=intraburstLevel, text="OFF", style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.normal)

label = label.new(bar_index=0, yloc=y_top, xloc=xloc.bar_index,
text=tostring(intraburstLevel, "0.00"), size=size.large,
color=color.black) label.location = location.top label.y = y_top
label.x = x_right label.text = tostring(intraburstLevel, "0.00")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a series, use a [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) operator.

Something like that:

```
plotshape(
  intraburstLevel > 30 ? intraburstLevel : na,
  text = "ON",
  style = shape.circle,
  location = location.abovebar,
  color = color.green,
  size = size.normal)
plotshape(
  intraburstLevel <= 30 ? intraburstLevel : na,
  text = "OFF",
  style = shape.circle,
  location = location.abovebar,
  color      = color.red,
  size = size.normal)
```

and the label

```
label.new(
  bar_index,
  close,
  tostring (intraburstLevel, "##.00"),
  color     = color.black,
  textcolor = color.white)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  in v5 i was using ta.min / ta.max hence too many arguements error.  And for others thx a lot.  If I want this intraburst to show only on wednesday candle, how can I code for that? Tuesday if Wednesday or Thursday (any of these two days) is a holiday. Should I post another question if you can help on this too?

Comment: Open a new question with this

Comment: Thank you.  [Question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75407242/plot-label-on-specific-day)