# Plot Label on Specific Day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

Below code plots On / Off everyday.  I want ON / OFF to appear only on Wednesday EOD, Tuesday if either Wednesday or Thursday is a holiday.  How can I do that?

Also, if intraburst is ON then, on next day, I will like to plot filter+VWAP as a line for whole of next day.  VWAP needs to be 9:20am value. Markets open at 9:15am for me.  I tried to code it but it is giving me error - Extraneous input ':' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' - and I do not know how to resolve it.  Removing ':' also does not help.  Any help on this too?

```
//@version=5
indicator('Intraburst', overlay=true)

truemove = math.abs(open[1] - close)
twoDayTrueHigh = math.max(high[1], high, close[2])
twoDayTrueLow = math.min(low[1], low, close[2])
twoDayTrueRange = twoDayTrueHigh - twoDayTrueLow
intraburstLevel = truemove / twoDayTrueRange * 100
filter = twoDayTrueRange*0.3

plotshape(intraburstLevel > 30 ? intraburstLevel : na, text='OFF', style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.normal)

plotshape(intraburstLevel <= 30 ? intraburstLevel : na, text='ON', style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.normal)

label.new(bar_index, close+0.8*filter, str.tostring(filter, '##.00'), color=color.black, textcolor=color.white)

if intraburstLevel <= 30 and time >= time(9, 20) and bar_index < bar_index[-1]:
    vwap = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",vwap)
    plot(bar_index + 1, vwap[1] + filter, color=color.green,linetype=linetype.solid, title="Filter + VWAP")
```

Comment: Almost every part of the last 3 lines makes no sense in Pine Script syntax. Tell chatGpt he's doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

About Wednesday:
You can use [dayofweek](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_dayofweek) to create a boolean

Something like that:

```
plotshape(
  intraburstLevel > 30 and dayofweek == 3 ? intraburstLevel : na,
  text='OFF',
  style=shape.circle,
  location=location.abovebar,
  color=color.new(color.red, 0),
  size=size.normal)

plotshape(
  intraburstLevel <= 30 and dayofweek == 3 ? intraburstLevel : na,
  text='ON',
  style=shape.circle,
  location=location.abovebar,
  color=color.new(color.green, 0),
  size=size.normal)
```

Note: There is no way to identify if a Wednesday is a holiday

Comment: Yes, agree holiday cant be determined by logic / sequence.  thx for the help